# IEnumerable reports compiler error when used with the namespace System.Collections

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, extension-methods

I was looking at this `Squares` extension method which was already there in Internet. I could not get this compiling. The compiler reports something like, **"The non-generic type `System.Collections.IEnumerable' cannot be used with the type arguments"**.

any ideas what is wrong with this code below ?

any help is much appreciated.

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Collections;

static class Program {

     static IEnumerable<int> Squares (this int from, int to) {
        for (int i=from;i<=to;i++)
        {
            yield return (int)i*i;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var min=1;
        foreach (int i in min.Squares(4))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your terminology is a bit off here. What you are getting is a *compiler error* and not an *exception*. Exceptions happen at runtime.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Yup, you are right. Edited :)

Comment: `IEnumerable` is a type and not a method and hence has no return type there's a different type `IEnumerable<T>` which is a generic type with one type argument

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Replace `using System.Collections;` with `using System.Collections.Generic;`.

Comment: That makes it. thanks. But, I also notice that with the namespace as `System.Collections`, the line `static IEnumerable Squares` also works. Why ? (notice, I dont specify any type as <int> there ?)

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed.: Because there are two interfaces: The non-generic [`System.Collections.IEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) and the generic [`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx).

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Thanks for pointing out that. Let me take a look.